# How to overwrite whole HTML with a new HTML through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Usecase**

I have a cache of the whole HTML of a webpage (including javascript and everything at https://example.org/**page1** ) in the database Redis.

Currently, My customer is on a webpage at ( https://example.org/**page2** ) which has its own set of HTML, event listeners, and javascript.

When my customer clicks on `GO TO PAGE 1` link on the `page2` then I want to fetch the cache HTML of `page 1` from Redis and overwrite the HTML content of `page2` instead of request go to the server to fetch `page`.

**What I have tried**

When a customer clicks on the `GO TO PAGE 1` link presented on the `page2` then I do the following

1. Make an ajax call to the Redis database
2. Fetch the whole HTML
3. Perform `document.open()`,`document.write()` & `document.close()` operation.
4. Replace the URL of `page 2` to the URL of the `page 1`.

**Issues I am getting**

While doing the above process, I am having the following observation.

1. After `document.write()` and `document.close()`, although HTML of `page2`is wiped out but Javascript and functions of `page2` are still in the memory and cause lots of errors like the duplicate firing of events tags etc with the javascript of `page1` (when `page1` is written through document.write). How can I even clean the javascript of `page2`
2. It seems `document.write()` is not the best practice then what are the alternatives of achieving the same functionality?

Can someone help me here with the above issues?

Considering the use case of fetching the `page1` through Ajax call and overwriting the `page2`, what is the right solution would you prefer?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use backend processing for this, such as PHP

Comment: Consider that duplicate javascript could be handled by checking for the existence of certain functions, variables, etc and overwriting them to do nothing if they will cause issues between page calls. Other than that, it is probably best to handle this with a backend solution that will deliver an entire page to the client on a fresh page call, and fall back to Redis when navigating between pages that have already been rendered in the browser. Out of curiosity, why are you relying on Redis instead of letting the server perform it's own caching of content?